# Webkit cutting off last character of a json feed

Tags: php, webkit, json

I'm creating a JSON feed with PHP using `echo json_encode($my_array)`.
The resulting string passed to the browser should be as shown below:
`[{"ACC_NUM":"147545","BOOK_DATE":"2011-10-22"},{"ACC_NUM":"147546","BOOK_DATE":"2011-10-22"}]`

In Firefox, the json string is received as shown. However, in webkit browsers (Safari, Chrome), the last character of the string gets cut off. This results in a parse error.

I've even tried serving the feed as application/json and text/html to no avail.

Does anyone know what's going on? Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks in advance.

BACKEND CODE:
// $result contains rows from a mysql query

```
if($result) {
    $arr = array();
    foreach($result as $key => $val) {
        $arr[$key] = $val;
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

this is saved in index.php which I can view in the browser and shows the resulting json feed.

Comment: It's impossible to tell given just the info you've given. Show your javascript code (and if possible your server-side code too).

Comment: Have you tried using the XHR console in Chrome to see the raw response? If it shows the full JSON string then it's probably a JavaScript issue.

Comment: I just tested this example: [stackoverflow.com/questions/8807558/how-to-create-forms-with-conditional-options/8808967#8808967](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807558/how-to-create-forms-with-conditional-options/8808967#8808967) in safari 4.0.4 (531.21.10) and chrome 16.0.912.75 m, both on win7. On both json is received and parsed correctly.

You should provide more information and/or working example with this bug.

Comment: So when go to `/index.php` in a webkit browser you see the final `[` missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who encounter this problem with Slimframework.
After echoing the json string, just add an exit command.

```
if($result) {
    $arr = array();
    foreach($result as $key => $val) {
        $arr[$key] = $val;
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
    exit; // <------------------- Hallelujah!!!
}
```